# Do WordPress Permalinks Refer to a Lookup Table in the Database?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, database

I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite URLs while dropping the original parameter (whether it's a number or text); basically exactly what WP does with it's clean permalinks

Does a database lookup table exist that matches the post ID# to the permalink string as set in the post editor?

Answer (score 1):

No, for the most part.

WordPress stores its rewrite rules in the database. These are pattern-based rules for mapping URLs onto query parameters, and are determined by the permalink structure you've chosen (e.g. `%post_name%`) and any additional structures plugins have provided.

For single items, WordPress extracts either `%post_id%` or `%post_name%` (slug) from the URL and fetches that post from the posts table.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a set of url patterns and matches (wp generate a number of url patters to satisfy user agents).
2. once you request lets say `domain.com/posts/2003/somestuff` url, wp tring to find a pattern that match this url inside a rewrite_rules (array that stored in `options` table by option name `rewrite_rules`)
3. once it found...  its parsed to query or better to say - matched_rule
4. matched rule basicly looks like dirty url (a url of wp site without turned on permalinks) , and matched_rule is a set of arguments that passed to WP_Query.
5. Once WP_Query get arguments and return some data (posts/pages/etc...) all of this data (wp_query and results) passed to view (template), index.php/single.php/etc.php
6. And here you got a page.

This is human explanation without (almost without) any tech details. Hope its undestandable for everyone who didn't work with rewrite_rules

Comment: Hi, though this may be true, this didn't really answer my question. I still don't understand how the post ID gets matched to the permalink string

Comment: It doesn't. Unless your permalink structure already contain post ID.